# Why QueryContainer is not updating from a Descriptor NESt C#

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Hi I have following descriptors in my NEST query...

```
queryContainer.DateRange(b => dateRangeDescriptor);
queryContainer.MatchPhrase(b => matchPhraseDescriptor);
```

And finally I use this QueryContainerDescriptor in the following **BoolQueryDescriptor**

```
boolDescriptor.Must(q => queryContainer);
```

The problem is although I could see values in my `dateRangeDescriptor` as well as `matchPhraseDescriptor`, it is not available in side `queryContainer`.

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Must` has the following overloads (in NEST 2.x)

```
public BoolQueryDescriptor<T> Must(
    params Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>[] queries) 
{ 
    // impl 
}

public BoolQueryDescriptor<T> Must(
    IEnumerable<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>> queries)
{
    // impl
}

public BoolQueryDescriptor<T> Must(
    params QueryContainer[] queries)
{
    // impl
}
```

So you need to pass a collection of queries to apply multiple `must` clauses rather than adding them all to one `QueryContainer`.